# Azure functions: how to debug csx in VS Code

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to debug an Azure function (CSX) on localhost in Visual Studio Code. I can attach a debugger, but I cannot put a breakpoint. Should I install something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, Functions CSX debugging in VS Code is not supported. VS Code debugging does not support full/desktop CLR, which is what CSX functions target.

Comment: though `func start` has an optional `--debug` parameter value `VSCode`

Comment: Has anything changed on this?

Answer (score 1):

Debugging csx files has been solved since the original answer.

[This blog](https://medium.com/cs-nerds/c-scripting-with-vscode-a-recipe-c672dd44d6) gives a broad tutorial including debugging.

The key is

```
dotnet script init
```

Which will set up the `launch.json` and `omnisharp.json` files needed. This config will debug whatever script file is open.

TIP: You may want to change `stopAtEntry` in `launch.json` to `false`. This setting confused me at first because it causes the program to halt before any breakpoint is reached, and seemingly before the script file is reached.