# How to debug Azure Functions using Visual Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have an existing set of functions in an Azure Functions App written in C# Script.  I've downloaded the zip file from the Azure portal and opened the directory in Visual Code. I can also log on to the Azure account from Visual Code and can see the functions. If I right-click, I get options to start and stop streaming logs

However, I don't know how to configure my environment so that I can edit and debug these functions locally. I've found instructions for creating a new Function App, but haven't found ones that describe how to work with an existing app.

Comment: Any update? Feel free to ask if you need further help, or could you accept the answer if it solves your question?

Comment: Thanks for the info Jerry. I did some more reading, and it seems like I need to stay with v1 of Azure Functions for now, as there are no .Net Core versions of the SharePoint CSOM or PnP modules at this stage. It also seems like debugging C# azure functions in Visual Code has additional challenges compared to full Visual Studio. I think I'll hold off on migrating from C# scripts to C# for now. I'll tackle it once I'm feeling braver

Comment: Reasonable choice, if you meet trouble in the future(hope it's never the case), feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745349/azure-functions-how-to-debug-csx-in-vs-code/45745756), for now we can't debug(add break points to) C# script(.csx) functions in VS Code.

We can only run csx function both on Azure and locally. Open the function app folder in VS code, follow steps below.

1. Check function runtime version(~1 or ~2) and follow [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) to install Azure Function core tools.
2. If we use ~2 runtime, you need to [register binding extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#register-extensions) for all triggers/in/output except Http and Timer triggers.
3. If we want to use settings(like AzureWebJobsStorage) in Application settings, copy them into `local.settings.json`. Or we can right click on Application settings of the Function app in VS Code, click Download Remote Settings(In this way, some invalid settings for local env are downloaded as well).
4. Input *Ctrl+`* to open terminal and input *func host start* in terminal to run functions.

For local dev, I do recommend you to use C# pre-compiled code instead of C# script, which is much easier to work with. To do this transformation, follow this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/create-app), new a c# function app locally, copy your code in .cs files. We basically don't need to modify the logic code except adding some package and namespace references.